# How to join a table using Context

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity, dbcontext

I have the following query

```
var table = Context.table
    .Include(x => x.extraTable);
```

I now want to perform a join on otherTable to other table.

If I was using SQL I would do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
INNER JOIN otherTable o
ON t.id = o.mainId
```

How can I do this with my query above.

I have tried things along the lines of

```
var table = Context.table
join Context.otherTable on (x => x.id = otherTable.id)
```

but no luck.

Either there is not much on Google about this, or I cannot find the correct terms to search for.

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate of the stated duplicate as I am using context, whilst the question mentioned is not

I have updated the question to show that I am using an include statement in my query.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes, only using entity

Comment: It is a duplicate... they are merely calling their context db... e.g. I call mine ctx

Comment: @PaulZahra apologies, I am using includes in my query, I should have included that in my initial question

Comment: No worries... basically the join line you want is along the lines of... join ot in context.OtherTable on t.id equals ot.Table_Id

Comment: @PaulZahra can you write that as an answer?